# Python subprocess piping

Tags: python

I am struggling to understand how to pipe commands using python.

What I want to do is:

```
echo 'subject:Hello World' | "/usr/bin/xxx -C -P Support\\XXX vmail"
```

I have tried this but it just throws the error "TypeError: bufsize must be an integer"

```
subprocess.call("echo","subject:xxx","|","/usr/bin/xxx","-C","-P","Support\\XXX","vmail")
```

Can this be done with python ?

## Edit

I managed to get it to work using the 2 processes, but what about if I want to pipe a python object (email message) to an external program as an object rather than converting it to a string and echoing it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *two* processes and pipe them together.

```
import subprocess

with open("/tmp/out.txt", "w") as o:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(["date"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(["cat"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=o)
```

This is equivalent to

```
$ date | cat > /tmp/out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess.check_output` with `shell=True`:

```
output=check_output("echo subject:Hello World | /usr/bin/xxx -C -P Support\\XXX vmail", shell=True)
```

here's an example:

```
>>> output=subprocess.check_output('echo subject:Hello World | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]', shell=True)
>>> output
'SUBJECT:HELLO WORLD\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this:

```
import os

os.system('"subject:Hello World" | "/usr/bin/xxx -C -P Support\\XXX vmail"')
```